# Insert start timestamp into org entry, like a deadline

Tags: org-mode

I want to record when I started an entry.

I'd like to have a key binding that creates an entry `STARTED ...`, like for `C-c C-d` (runs the command `org-deadline`).

Existing https://orgmode.org/manual/Creating-Timestamps.html  `C-c .` (`org-time-stamp`) lacks the word STARTED and it set a date at point - I want it to set/update automatically as a header, like `org-deadline` (or `C-c C-t` `org-todo`).

Should it be a custom function? Is there something built-in?

Comment: I'd suggest that you use a `STARTED` property instead in some property drawer (perhaps `LOGBOOK`). `DEADLINE` and `SCHEDULED` are special: they have agenda implications whereas `STARTED` would just be a timestamp with no such implications (indeed the agenda would have no idea about a `STARTED` keyword.